# Ошибка Django: Reverse not found. 'teachers_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-model

Я новичок в Django. Использую туториал https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django, но застрял на 5 части.
Я создал приложение "education" в проекте "edusys". Я пытаюсь получить список преподавателей из базы данных и хочу, чтобы по нажатию на ФИО каждого я переходил в профиль каждого преподавателя, где можно уже отдельно увидеть информацию из базы данных о нём (что-то типа профиля, как в соц.сетях).

Я получаю следующую ошибку, запуская сервер и переходя на url /teachers :

[Reverse for 'teachers_detail' not found. 'teachers_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7ad.png)

Что я делаю не так? Не могу решить проблему уже 3 недели, ничего не помогает. Ошибка появляется из-за функции get_absolute_url в моделях, реверс не может найти teachers_detail.

Файлы моего проекта:

**education/models.py :**

```python
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Teachers(models.Model):
    tcode = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    department_s = models.ForeignKey('Departments', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    employee_post = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    academic_degree = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    GENDER_UNIT = (
        ('m', 'Мужчина'),
        ('f', 'Женщина'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_UNIT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.middle_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("teachers_detail", args=[str(self.tcode)])
```

**education/urls.py :**

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

```
app_name = 'education'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('teachers/', views.TeachersListView.as_view(), name='teachers'),
    path('teachers/<int:tcode>', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
]
```

**education/views.py :**

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Teachers
from django.views import generic

class TeachersListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Teachers
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'teachers_list' 
    template_name = 'education/teachers_list.html'


class TeachersDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teachers
    #book_id=Teachers.objects.get(pk=Teachers.tcode)
```

**education/teachers_list.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container"><div class="col-12"><h1>Teachers list</h1></div></div>
<div class="container">
  
  {% if teachers_list %}
  
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          
          {% for Teachers in teachers_list %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="{{ Teachers.get_absolute_url }}">{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name|default_if_none:"" }}</a> ({{Teachers.department_s}})</td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td>{{ Teachers.email }}</a></td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="profile.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Профиль</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
  {% else %}
    <p>list is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

**education/teachers_detail.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>email:</strong> {{ Teachers.email }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>department:</strong> {{ Teachers.department_s }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>employee post:</strong> {{ Teachers.employee_post }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>academic dehree:</strong> {{ Teachers.academic_degree }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Ошибка в указании имени `url`.

У вас в конфиге указан `app_name`. Если он указан, то урлы из этого файла берутся с `app_name` как алиасом (пространство имен)

```
app_name = 'education'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('teachers/', views.TeachersListView.as_view(), name='teachers'),
    path('teachers/<int:tcode>', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
]
```

То есть, вам надо заменить ваши `reverse("teachers_detail", ...)` на `reverse("education:teachers_detail", ...)`. Прочтить об этом можно было [в доке по урлам](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#id5).

```
return reverse("education:teachers_detail", args=[self.tcode])
```

---

**UPD**

Еще у вас в урл с int полем передается str тип. Лучше передавать то, что указано.

То есть вместо

```
reverse("education:teachers_detail", args=[str(self.tcode)])
```

стоит писать

```
reverse("education:teachers_detail", args=[self.tcode])
```

Спасибо @Vadim.Sharoikin , который заметил это

Comment: а int с str конфликтовать не будут? в urls указанно `int:tcode` а в аргумент передается строка

Comment: а на счет этого не  уверен, не проверял. обычно передаю то, что указано в описании. но в любом случае, вы об этом узнаете сразу.

Comment: узнаю только в том случае если автор вопроса, напишет вопрос о новой ошибке) или тут еще что-то спросит

Comment: Боже мой, Вы меня просто спасли!!!!! Спасибо огромное, теперь наконец-то всё работает!!! Единственное, только, на странице teachers_detail.html никаких данных не отображается, может, тоже сможете что-то подсказать?